# How to align text with other div elements which are set as display: inline-block

Tags: html, css

I have three divs, of differing heights which I need to align in a straight line horizontally. Currently, I have set them as `display: inline-block` but they are not aligned correctly. If I set a top or bottom margin, it still doesn't resolve itself. Any ideas how I could fix this?

```css
/*toggle switch */
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative; width: 54px;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #3273F0; border-radius: 20px;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 24px; padding: 0; line-height: 24px;
    font-size: 14px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "";
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #f6f6f6; color: #FFFFFF;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "";
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #f6f6f6; color: #999999;
    text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block; width: 22px; margin: 3px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 26px;
    border: 2px solid #3273F0; border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px; 
    background-color: #3273F0; 
}
```

```html
<div>
<div style="display: inline-block"> Male</div>
<div style="display: inline-block" class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" tabindex="0" checked="">
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block"> Fermale</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new CSS selector for `div` and add the styling `vertical-align: center;`

```css
/*toggle switch */
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative; width: 54px;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
div {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #3273F0; border-radius: 20px;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 24px; padding: 0; line-height: 24px;
    font-size: 14px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "";
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #f6f6f6; color: #FFFFFF;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "";
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #f6f6f6; color: #999999;
    text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block; width: 22px; margin: 3px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 26px;
    border: 2px solid #3273F0; border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px; 
    background-color: #3273F0; 
}
```

```html
<div>
<div style="display: inline-block"> Male</div>
<div style="display: inline-block" class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" tabindex="0" checked="">
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block"> Female</div>

</div>
```